# how to use shedskin to convert python code to c++ code?

Tags: c++, python, converters

I read I [document](http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/wiki/docs) provided but can't understand how to use shedskin, I'm not experienced at python.
I have python 2.7, I test it seems it works in cmd, or if I just double click on .py file it produce .pyc file.
I run tests in shedskin\shedskin-0.9.1\shedskin\tests by clicking run.py it produce some .cpp and makefile, but I can't understand how to run it on my .py files?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with all this?

Comment: does this not work for you? if not please elaborate more on the specific problems you encounter. http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/wiki/docs#Compiling_a_Stand-Alone_Program

Comment: I run init.bat in main folder and then try 
`code`"shedskin my.py" 
- no such file,
`code` "shedskin C:\my.py" - module name must consist...
also try to cd to my dir, nothing works, the question is how to run it in cmd or where I must put my .py file.

Comment: I managed to run test by "shedskin test", but can't understand how to put my dir with .py in command line.

Comment: at all I anderstand, cd to my folder and run "shedskin my"  (without extension)

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir helloworld
cd helloworld
echo -e "import sys\nprint 'hello '+sys.argv[1]" > helloworld.py
python helloworld.py this_is_python
shedskin helloworld
make
./helloworld this_is_c_plus_plus
```

Comment: python shed skin simple example.  python shedskin simple example.